# Using formulas in a google form response sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have a google form that asks for a person's name, and based on their name I want to add data to two columns. I've written the formula, =if(ISBLANK(D18),"",VLOOKUP(D18,Students!A12:E372,4,FALSE)), but whenever the form is submitted, the formula gets overwritten and the column ends up blank. Is there a way to protect this formula so the data can be saved properly upon the form being submitted?

I tried protecting the columns, but the data got overwritten anyways. I tried making a new sheet and copying the original sheet's data over, but on data submission the line with the data got deleted on the new sheet.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gB6wsfxaGGJ6kzQsS0_YEXXj5VF-s83i600m77bCH4o/edit?usp=sharing) 

The issue I have is that the formulas in columns K and L get overwritten every time someone submits the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array formula in the header

```
={"Header";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",,VLOOKUP(D2:D,Students!A12:E372,4,FALSE)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form submissions INSERT a new row pushing the formula down to the next row.  They are set up that way to prevent loss of entry submissions data.

In the sample below, the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(B3:B)` was in cell C2 before an entry was submitted.  It has been moved to cell C3.

[image]

It is better practice to set up your formulas on a second tab and then do what you need with the data on that tab.

**Note:**  The previously posted answer would work, however.  This just explains what the issue is and the best practice for handling form submission data.